# Why am I getting a white screen in the MODx manager?

Tags: modx

My MODx website is working, but when I log in to the manager, all I see is a tool bar, but no other content.

The MODx error log reports:

```
[2016-09-16 08:55:17] (ERROR in xPDOConnection::connect @ /somepath/html/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php : 2998) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'someserver.com' (4)
```

The public part of the site is up, so this error confuses me. I am hosted at MediaTemple.